# No Shawdow in toolbar Pre-5.0 version in android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am trying to set shadow in toolbar for pre-Lollipop version. Hence trying the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_shadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webviewPage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarforWeb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And Java file:

```
public class AboutUs extends AppCompatActivity
{

    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar mIndeterminateProgress;
    private AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> mLicenseLoader;
    private String versionName;
    private String deviceId;
    private Toolbar mActionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.webcode);

        mActionBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (mActionBar != null)
        {
            setSupportActionBar(mActionBar);
            getSupportActionBar().setElevation(20);
        }

        mActionBar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blackText));

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_aboutus));

        final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
        upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blackText), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        mActionBar.setNavigationIcon(upArrow);

        mActionBar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha));
        mActionBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

     }
   }
```

Style is like this: On StyleV14 XML

```
<style name="Theme.ylg" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow</item>
    </style>
```

<5.0 tried on Galaxy Nexus running 4.3 (There is no shadow)

[image]

5.0 and more tried on Nexus 5 running 5.1 (This shows shadow)

[image]

Is there something else that I have to add to version 14 style?

Answer (score 0):

you can customize it with windowTitle

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
      <item name="android:background">#222222</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomWindowTitleTextStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```